# HTML img align="middle" doesn't align an image

Tags: html, css, image

I want a image to be centered aligned. Image size is fixed in pixels.

So what I want is like this-

[image: 1].

What I have done is-

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <img
        src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/rokey/popo-emotions/128/big-smile-icon.png"
        width="42" height="42"
        align="middle"
        style="float: left;
          position: relative;
          display: block;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
          z-index: 1;"
        >

</body>
</html>
```

But I am getting-

[image: 22]

I want it to be responsive.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Styling, such as width and height, should be specified only in CSS in the ``<style>`` part of the ``<head>``, not in HTML in the body.  If you want it to be responsive, don't use absolute units (e.g. "42"); instead use relative units, such as ``width: auto; height: 3em;`` or ``height: auto; width: 5%; min-width: 1em;``.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about this? I frequently use the CSS Flexible Box Layout to center something.

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/rokey/popo-emotions/128/big-smile-icon.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Flex boxes are an unnecessarily complicated and browser-dependent way to do such a simple thing.

Comment: I think it's not so complicated (hey, this just uses two properties :D), but you're right, it won't work on old IEs. It still won't be a problem when one targets evergreen browsers. I prefer to use `flex` because it's extensible and easy to use for several positioning situation.

Answer (score 40):

The attribute `align=middle` sets *vertical* alignment. To set horizontal alignment using HTML, you can wrap the element inside a `center` element and remove all the CSS you have now.

```html
<center><img src=
"http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/rokey/popo-emotions/128/big-smile-icon.png"
width="42" height="42"></center>
```

If you would rather do it in CSS, there are several ways. A simple one is to set `text-align` on a container:

```html
<div style="text-align: center"><img src=
"http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/rokey/popo-emotions/128/big-smile-icon.png"
width="42" height="42"></div>
```

Comment: if you don't have any plans to use css . the first answer is the best one as i think.                                                                                                  <center><img src=
"http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/rokey/popo-emotions/128/big-smile-icon.png"
width="42" height="42"></center>

Comment: "The attribute `align` sets vertical alignment" - O'RLY?Tthen what does allowed "left" value mean vertically? https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#adef-align-IMG

Answer (score 6):

remove `float: left` from image css and add `text-align: center` property in parent element `body`

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="text-align: center;">

    <img
        src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/rokey/popo-emotions/128/big-smile-icon.png"
        width="42" height="42"
        align="middle"
        style="
          
          display: block;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
          z-index: 1;"
        >

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change 'middle' to 'center'. Like so:

```
<img align="center" ....>
```

Comment: Seems that `center` is not amongst [allowed values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-align)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
style="margin: auto"
```

Answer (score 0):

remove float left.

Edited: removed reference to align center on an image tag.

Comment: Setting `align` to `center` is invalid for an `img` element and has no effect.

Comment: Thanks, completely escaped me.

Answer (score 0):

just remove `float: left` and replace align with `margin: 0 auto` and it will be centered.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `align="center"` and `float:left`. Remove both of these. `margin: 0 auto` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In image tag we use **align:center** property to make image center

```
<img alt='Logo' src={ logo } width='254.53px' height='56px' align={ 'center' }/>
```