# Float image in center

Tags: css, html

I have an inline image in a paragraph. I want to float that image in the middle of the paragraph.
I tried to center it with...

```
<center>
```

...but I saw it was depreciated in HTML5.
I tried to use float it with...

```
<img style="float: middle;">
```

...but it turns out that that doesn't even exist.

Is there a short way to do this, preferably inside the img tag, like with the style attribute?
Here is my HTML so far...

```
<p>
    <img id="resize" width="70%" src="../logo.png" alt="Alt" style="CENTER THIS IMAGE... SOMEHOW...">
</p>
```

Comment: Orion closed this question but didn't bother to link to the original answer. So, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28336888/html-img-align-middle-not-working

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it inline using `style="display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"`

or add it to a css class

```
    .myimage {
        display:block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

**Updated Based on CBore comment**

Comment: Dang. beat me to it!

Comment: You try with style="vertical-align: middle;"

Comment: You can put your code html and css?

Comment: Auto margins need `display:block` to work here as well.

Comment: CBore is correct I missed that line

Comment: That works now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could just add `text-align: center;` to the `<p>` tag

Like `<p style="text-align:center">`

Comment: Yes! That works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size you want it to be you can put a margin on left and right to equal 100. for instance

```
 <!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
#resize{
margin-left:15%; 
margin-right:15%;
}
</style>
<body>

<div>
<p>
    <img id="resize" width="70%" src="http://codingkids.businesscatalyst.com/logo.png" alt="Alt" >
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cleaner method, and the method to use if you are not statically setting a width is to do like CBroe said and put display:block in CSS for the img. I guess I'm just to used to using bootstrap for all my centering needs

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's inside a 100% width paragraph. I'm not sure what framework you're working in, but, can you just add the css property (text-align:center;) to that paragraph tag?

Comment: I am working in HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, Foundation and w3.css